# polyline for Mapview

Tags: android, android-mapview

Is there anything for the Google mapview that is analogous to the “polyline” that exists in other mapping systems?  Basically it’s a collection of locations along with drawing information (color weight, etc).  You fill it with locations and do a Map.Children.Add(myPolyline) and you have a route drawn on the map.
I’m aware that I can sweat it out drawing with canvas.drawPath() but I want to make sure I’m using best practices before I start with a new app.
Thanks,
Gary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question looks very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667728/android-polylines-maps-api).

Although I've never drawn on MapView, it seems that all questions about path drawing point back to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1939659/953105).

Comment: That answer is what I referred to as "sweating it out."  Turns out there is no polyline in google API.  I can live with that.  Thanks.